# Comparing dates in hive not returning what expected

Tags: sql, hive

I'm doing some comparison with dates, and when I do the following:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a11.duedate),'dd-MM-yyyy') < 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

**returns false**

The a11.duedate is 21-02-2018 and is returning false when comparing with today's date.

When I compare it in miliseconds, **returns true**:

```
unix_timestamp(a11.duedate) < unix_timestamp()
```

What I am missing here? In my view, both conditions should return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing all this conversion?  There is no need to go to unix timestamps for this.  Assuming the value is stored as a date (which it should be):

```
a11.duedate < CURRENT_DATE()
```

If it is not stored as a date, then I believe you can do:

```
unix_timestamp(a11.duedate, 'dd-MM-yyyy') < unix_timestamp(current_date())
```

Or, if you want to practice arithmetic:

```
unix_timestamp(a11.duedate, 'dd-MM-yyyy') < floor(current_timestamp / (24*60*60)) * 24*60*60
```

Comment: thank you, a11.duedate < CURRENT_DATE() worked just fine. But yet, I think even converting it should also work, right?

Comment: @TiagoFernandes . . . Don't convert if you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard `yyyy-MM-dd` comparison. Note that the return type of `from_unixtime` is `string` and hence you get `false` (because of the string comparison) with the query you run.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a11.duedate,'dd-MM-yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
< from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

One more option is compare the unix timestamps rather than converting them to date strings.